# Удаление блока по нажатию кнопки в этом блоке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, css-animation

Есть вот такой код удаления объекта.

```js
document.onclick = function() {
  div = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card'));
  div.forEach((e) => {
    e.onclick = function() {
      this.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.card {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #ccc;
}

#overlay button {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card show">
  <div id="overlay">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light position-absolute " onclick="removeWishList();">
    Remove from list
    </button>
  </div>
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="i/Huawei-Mate-S.png" alt="Huawei Mate S">
  <div class="card-body">
    <span class="separator mx-auto"></span>
    <h5 class="card-title">Huawei Mate S</h5>
    <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Удалить</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на область элемента `card` - он удаляется. Необходимо, что бы при нажатии на кнопки: **"Remove from list"**, **"Удалить"** производилось удаление родительского элемента `card`.

Подскажите где я что-то не добавил или же не так написал ?
Буду премного благодарен вам ;)

Comment: спустя 2.5 года, супер стыдно смотреть на это))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть разные способы:

1. Повесить обработчик на каждую кнопку и танцевать от нее (искать способ удалить нужный элемент).
2. Делегировать событие.

Можно еще подумать, но ниже я использовал делегирование. Обработчик повесил на `document`, но можно повесить на родительский блок, в котором будут храниться элементы `card`. В моем примере, это ускорит поиск нужно элемента. Так же я использовал [атрибут data-*](https://webref.ru/html/attr/data), по которому искал нужные кнопки для удаления, но можно через `class` или `id` находить нужные кнопки, или придумать еще какой либо способ.

```js
function removeElem(delElem, attribute, attributeName) {
//проверка на наличие всех аргументов.
  if (!(delElem && attribute && attributeName)) return;
//возвращаем функцию, которая будет иметь доступ к аргументам, и при этом будет в себе хранить объект события.
  return function(e) {
 //Узнаем на каком элементе был произведен клик.
    let target = e.target;
//Делаем проверку на наличие атрибута "data-del", и проверяем на наличие параметра "delete".
    if (!(target.hasAttribute(attribute) ?
        (target.getAttribute(attribute) === attributeName ? true : false) : false)) return;
    let elem = target;
//После мы производим поиск элемента, который нужно удалить. Поиск идет снизу вверх. За счет того, что кнопки находяться внутри "card", то мы точно удалить нужный нам "card"(сорри за тавтологию).
    while (target != this) {
      if (target.classList.contains(delElem)) {
        target.remove();
        return;
      }
      target = target.parentNode;
    }
    return;
  };
}


document.addEventListener("click", removeElem("card", "data-del", "delete"));
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #ccc;
}

#overlay button {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card show">
  <div id="overlay">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light position-absolute" data-del="delete">
    Remove from list 1
    </button>
  </div>
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="i/Huawei-Mate-S.png" alt="Huawei Mate S">
  <div class="card-body">
    <span class="separator mx-auto"></span>
    <h5 class="card-title">Huawei Mate S</h5>
    <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-del="delete">Удалить</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card show">
  <div id="overlay">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light position-absolute" data-del="delete">
    Remove from list 2
    </button>
  </div>
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="i/Huawei-Mate-S.png" alt="Huawei Mate S">
  <div class="card-body">
    <span class="separator mx-auto"></span>
    <h5 class="card-title">Huawei Mate S</h5>
    <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-del="delete">Удалить</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card show">
  <div id="overlay">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light position-absolute" data-del="delete">
    Remove from list 3
    </button>
  </div>
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="i/Huawei-Mate-S.png" alt="Huawei Mate S">
  <div class="card-body">
    <span class="separator mx-auto"></span>
    <h5 class="card-title">Huawei Mate S</h5>
    <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-del="delete">Удалить</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card show">
  <div id="overlay">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light position-absolute" data-del="delete">
    Remove from list 4
    </button>
  </div>
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="i/Huawei-Mate-S.png" alt="Huawei Mate S">
  <div class="card-body">
    <span class="separator mx-auto"></span>
    <h5 class="card-title">Huawei Mate S</h5>
    <p class="card-text">$280.00</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-del="delete">Удалить</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чётко, развернуто и понятно.
Огромное спасибо ;)

Comment: @Nick, всегда пожалуйста, но вопросы старайтесь более лучше документировать. Вот полезная ссылка: [Stack Overflow: Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).